# Beautiful Soup 4 findall() not matching elements from the <img> tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup 4 to help me download an image from Imgur, although I doubt the Imgur part is relevant. As an example, I'm using the webpage here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE4yx.jpg

My code is as follows:

```py
import webbrowser, time, sys, requests, os, bs4      # Not all libraries are used in this code snippet
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE4yx.jpg")

res = requests.get(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE4yx.jpg)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="html.parser")

imageElement = soup.findAll('img', {'class': 'post-image-placeholder'})
print(imageElement)
```

The HTML code on the Imgur link contains a part that reads as:

```
<img alt="" src="//i.imgur.com/JfLsH5y.jpg" class="post-image-placeholder" style="max-width: 100%; min-height: 546px;" original-title="">
```

which I found by picking the first image element on the page using the point and click tool in Inspect Element.

The problem is that I would expect there to be two items in imageElement, one for each image, however, the print function shows `[]`. I have also tried other forms of `soup.findAll('img', {'class': 'post-image-placeholder'})` such as `soup.findall("img[class='post-image-placeholder']")` but that made no difference.

Furthermore, when I used

```
imageElement = soup.select("h1[class='post-title']")
```

,just to test, the print function did return a match, which made me wonder if it had something to do with the  tag.

```
[<h1 class="post-title">Cable management increases performance. </h1>]
```

Thank you for your time and effort

Comment: Have you ran `print(res.text)` to actually verify the image is in the HTML when the page is first requested? It's fairly common for websites to load a page and then use JavaScript to insert elements.

Comment: @SpencerD Ah, I just ran it and I could not find any image tags. Thanks for pointing that out! Do you have any idea how I could get the updated HTML please? Thank you !

Comment: Yeah, one sec and I'll post an answer along those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem here seems to be that the actual `<img ...>` element is not present when the page is first loaded. The best solution to this, in my opinion, would be to take advantage of the selenium webdriver that you already have available to grab the image. Selenium will allow the page to properly render (with JavaScript and all), and then locate whatever elements you care about.

For example:

```
import webbrowser, time, sys, requests, os, bs4      # Not all libraries are used in this code snippet
from selenium import webdriver

# For pretty debugging output
import pprint


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://imgur.com/t/lenovo/mLwnorj")

# Give the page up to 10 seconds of a grace period to finish rendering
# before complaining about images not being found.
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

# Find elements via Selenium's search
selenium_image_elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('img.post-image-placeholder')
pprint.pprint(selenium_image_elements)

# Use page source to attempt to find them with BeautifulSoup 4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="html.parser")

soup_image_elements = soup.findAll('img', {'class': 'post-image-placeholder'})
pprint.pprint(soup_image_elements)
```

<strike>I cannot say that I have tested this code yet on my side,</strike> but the general concept should work.

---

Update:

I went ahead and tested this on my side, fixed some errors in the code, and I then got the results I was hoping to see:

[image: Output from running code]

Answer (score 2):

If a website will insert objects after page load you will need to use Selenium instead of `requests`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://imgur.com/t/lenovo/mLwnorj'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
images = soup.find_all('img', {'class': 'post-image-placeholder'})

[print(image['src']) for image in images]

# //i.imgur.com/JfLsH5yr.jpg
# //i.imgur.com/lLcKMBzr.jpg
```